# F# WSDL code generation

Tags: wcf, soap, f#, wsdl

I'm using VS.NET 2010 integrated shell with F# and I'm trying to consume a soap web service... How do I go about generating F# source? I tried

> wsdl l:"C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll" http://localhost/?wsdl

Along with

> wsdl /language:"Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=1.9.2.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809"

However I can't seem to get the /language switch to work.

EDIT:

taspeotis' answer got me going... This generated F# source for the web service:

```
gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.dll"
svcutil /language:"Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider, FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809" http://localhost/?wsdl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added `FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll` to the GAC? Use [gacutil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this.

### 3rd party edit

Here an example  `gacutil.exe /l System.XML.Linq` to list certain assemblies.
Besides to [FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom/) ([source](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom)) an alternative might be the [FSharp.Data library](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/)

Quote from jizugu: `This generated F# source for the web service:`

```
gacutil -i 
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

svcutil 
  /language:"Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider  
        ,FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
        ,PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809" http://localhost/?wsdl
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but you may have better luck generating C#, compiling that C# into a library DLL, and referencing that DLL from your F# code.  (The C# compiler csc.exe will be part of your .NET installation.)

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if the F# Code DOM provider worked with WSDL. I wrote the initial implementation some time ago while at Microsoft and we got it to work with ASP.NET, but unless it has been improved since then, it probably won't work with WSDL or XSD.

Even for ASP.NET, we had to create a separate class that included some ASP.NET specific "hacks". This was partly because the CodeDOM generated by ASP.NET was invalid (in a way) and because the CodeDOM structure is not quite compatible with F#. If you really need to get this to work, you may have to add similar hacks (by modifying the [source from CodePlex](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/))

I tink that a safer approach is to include a small C# library project that generates the reference for you or invoking the C# compiler using `csc.exe` as Brian suggests.

Comment: Yeah, I got code to spit out but it definitely needs modification to get going.